# How can I deploy my Angular2+ app as the back end, with a static landing page as the front end?

Tags: angular

This is an extremely common website pattern, so I'm surprised to find no simple answer on the web. I need a static `index.html` page that displays, for example, a restaurant menu and hours. I also need the usual `about.html`, `contact.html`, etc, each with a link to 'login', which is my Angular app, which allows a registered user to login and reserve a table, for example, or allows an admin to login and make db changes, etc.

I currently have a hodge podge setup of a static _index.html page, using htaccess to redirect to it instead of index.html (my app) and linking into index.html from _index.html and other static pages. This seems very hack-y and routing within the app's routes has some very strange side effects.

**What is the best practice way to deploy a few static pages that link to a 'back end' Angular app?**

I have seen Angular Universal, but I don't grok how server side rendering alone solves this problem. Detailed explanations or links to detailed resources would be great, since the very few answers I've found on this topic say very vague things like "just link into your app", instead of describing the full structure of the deployment.

EDIT: Since there is still confusion about what I thought was a very common pattern on the web, I'll restate with a better example. The confusion may be: *every project I have written so far has immediately displayed a login page.* This is my first attempt at including pretty HTML/CSS landing pages.

Users who navigate to example.com should see a web page that shows 'static' HTML/CSS information about a conference event. This page does not need to show any dynamic content from any database or even run any javascript, only "wow, look at this great conference, you should go to it". There might be a few other HTML/CSS pages that display the event details and information about the people hosting the conference. 1990s technology so far. Call all of these pages the 'front end'.

Each of these pages has a link to 'login', where anyone interested in attending the conference can login/register, RSVP, reserve a table, and even return later with their new credentials to print their ticket...my Angular App. I have called this the 'back end'.

**How should I organize the project to serve this static HTML content, "wow, look at this conference", and also the register, login, RSVP, etc. Angular components?** Do I need to create a wrapper component for each of the 'static' pages just so they can live within the app and its routes, or is there some better way to have some content in front of a login and some content behind a login?

I am not trying to optimize an already working solution or do anything overly exotic -- at least I thought before I found so few examples and read the confused replies to this question. So, if the answer is "put everything, even 'static' pages, into your Angular app as components", then so be it. I just want to make sure that is not an amateur hack-y way to do things when there may be a better "Angular way" to do it. My reluctance to make a component for each of the 'static' pages is that my partners only know HTML and cannot easily edit -- and re-deploy -- any of that content if it is rolled into the app.

Comment: What's wrong with having those static pages inside an angular app?

Comment: I think there's a little bit of confusion due to the phrasing that was used. Angular is a client side only service that can be rendered on the server (back-end) using angular universal. 

From your description it sounds like you want to link to your angular app (for authorization) from a separate webpage. Is this correct?

Comment: Restated: When **any** user browses to example.com, they should see index.html, which will display some information about the business -- plain html content that doesn't need to be dynamic -- this html page also displays a link, labeled 'login', so a registered user can log in, then do many different 'backend' activities. There is no separate web page. I am confused now by how exotic this concept seems to be, since there are so many examples on the web. I don't actually care if the 'static' page(s) are within my Angular app or discrete .html pages, only that I'm following best practices.

Comment: Maybe I'm over-complicating a simple concept? I'm currently using route guards to send any not-logged-in user or any nonsense routes to my loginComponent at a /login route. Should I instead make a wrapper component for my 'static' landing page, and send not-logged-in users to that wrapper component so it becomes teh 'default' that any user sees? Wouldn't this bring all the Angular overhead along with displaying that first landing page and any others I wrap in a component? Again, best practices desired.